# kubectl logs deploy/my-deployment does not show logs from all pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

What is the purpose of `kubectl logs deploy/my-deployment` shown at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-deployments-and-services?

I would think it will show me logs from all the pods deployed as part of the `my-deployment` object. However, even though I have 2 pods in my deployment, that command shows logs from only one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your deployment has multiple pod replicas, then `kubectl logs deployment/...` will just pick one on its own.

Here is an example:

```
kubectl  get pods -n kube-system | grep coredns
coredns-78fcd69978-dqf95       1/1     Running   0          42h
coredns-78fcd69978-vgvf2       1/1     Running   0          42h
```

```
kubectl logs deployment/coredns -n kube-system 
Found 2 pods, using pod/coredns-78fcd69978-vgvf2
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> logs -l <label_selector> --all-containers=true -f --tail=25
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you @Brad. I have a deployment with 3 replicas. This command shows logs from all the 3 pods. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the documentation you linked:

```
kubectl logs deploy/my-deployment                         # dump Pod logs for a Deployment (single-container case)
kubectl logs deploy/my-deployment -c my-container         # dump Pod logs for a Deployment (multi-container case)
```

`kubectl logs deploy/my-deployment` is used when you have just one container. So in your case is probably taking the first one. If you have multiple containers you have to specify one with `-c` option.

If you want to have logs from multiple pods, you can use [Stern](https://github.com/wercker/stern)

Comment: But I have a single container per pod. I think that's what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

By following documentation provided, when there are multiple Pods using the below command, it displays logs from only one Pod at a time it will pick randomly one at a point of time.

kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep coredns

If there are multiple containers then one can specify by using “-c” and mention the container name.
By following the Stren documentation, one can get the logs from multiple containers within a pod. Using the below command will display the multiple container data.

kubectl logs deploy/my-deployment -c my-container

Comment: I have just one container per pod.

Comment: pick is definitely not random. You can check actual algorithm behind [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/f7d2ecdc3e52b408833aa6269c57ad9ef408467e/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/util/podutils/podutils.go#L87)